# History of asymptotic expansion of Laplace’s method between Laplace and Erdélyi

Tags: ho.history-overview, asymptotics, divergent-series

**In 1774** Laplace understood that $I≔∫\textrm{d}x \exp kf(x)$ for $k≫0$ can be estimated if one knows 2-jet of $f$ at its point of maximum (as $I₀ ≔ ∫\textrm{d}x \exp kf₀(x)$ with $f₀$ quadratic with the same 2-jet as $f$. — And $I₀$ is easy to calculate explicitly).  **In 1956** Erdélyi wrote (in his book) a formula improving Laplace’s $\lim_{k→∞} I/I₀ = 1$ to an asymptotic expansion in $1/k$ for $I/I₀$ (in terms of the higher jet of $f$ at its maximum).  Unfortunately, I’m not able to find a lot of info on what has been happening during these 180 years in between!

The first such an asymptotic expansion I can find is an example done in the famous paper by Debye of 1909.  There are two major sub-themes:

1. He covered one-step-more-advanced context (the steepest descent — when $f$ is allowed to be complex), but these “more advanced” parts were not new¹⁾.
2. He wrote down “the extra terms” of the asymptotic expansion in $1/k$.

> ¹⁾ He attributes these “more advanced” parts to Riemann’s posthumous publication of 1876 (of his notes of 1863) and Graf–Gubler’s book of 1898.  (He did not know about [Ph.D. thesis of Pavel Nekrasov of 1886](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82753808.pdf#page=11).)

Well, the Debye’s paper is usually considered as the trail-blazing work in the method of steepest descent.  From this *I guess* that it *must be* “the part **(2)**” which makes this paper the fundamental reference on this subject.

**But his approach to *(2)* makes sense in the real case too!** So below I ignore **(1)** completely: my questions are *about what makes sense in purely-real cases too*.

**Question:** was Debye indeed the first one to write these extra terms?  135 years between Laplace and Debye seems to be too long a gap — during these years a lot of mathematicians focused on approximate calculations…

**Likewise:** Have there been other significant attempts on this subject in 45 years between Debye and Erdélyi?²⁾

> ²⁾ For example: J.R. Airey³⁾ already in ’37 “jumped two steps ahead”: when tabulating special functions, he started to investigate “what is happening beyond superasymptotics”.  (Essentially, these were traces of Dingle’s resurgence — what is now called *hyperasymptotics*…)

> ³⁾ … who is not G.B. Airy — although IIRC he worked with asymptotic expansions of Airy function as well!

**Update:** Split Debye’s results in two parts, and accentuate the interest to the “purely real case”.

Answer (score 1):

The article [*The origin of the method of steepest descent*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0315086096921461) covers the pre-Debye history, tracing the method back to a 1829 paper by Cauchy, "Mémoire sur divers points d’analyse". Contributions by Riemann (1863) and Nekrasov (1885) are also discussed.

Comment: Sure!  Did you notice that the original question contains a live link to this article?  (The article discusses what I call above “the extra step” — which is orthogonal to the topic of asymptotic expansion…)

Comment: hmm, so Cauchy does not count as a "contribution to Laplace’s method between Laplace and Erdélyi" ?

Comment: He contributed (wrongly/misguidedly, according to the cited paper — this is why I decided not to mention him among others, above) to the steepest descent method, not to the Laplace method.

Comment: I made an update accentuating the interest in the “purely real case”.